# Convert Date in SQL

Tags: sql

```
Select ReceiveDate,SentDate
From Customers

ReceiveDate                    SentDate
2012-11-29 19:17:00         2007-08-28 10:48:00
```

I want to change such format is : Month Day, Year (Example : Nov 29, 2012)

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: How should we help you, without knowing which Database you use?

Comment: There's nothing that people involved in development projects seem to love more than fiddling with date formats -- everyone has an opinion, and most of it is hot air. Fortunately there is an international standard, and your data presentation already matches it. Best to leave it as it is.

Comment: What is your end display location?  Although I have no doubt the existing queries will work, You're really better off doing the conversion in your end, display, layer.  For example, in an application, transforming it only during display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what RDBMS, but if you are using SQL Server, you can use:

```
select 
  convert(varchar(6), receivedate, 100)+', '+cast(year(receivedate) as char(4)) ReceiveDate,
  convert(varchar(6), sentdate, 100)+', '+cast(year(sentdate) as char(4)) SentDate
from customers
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f4bc/9)

Result:

```
|  RECEIVEDATE |     SENTDATE |
-------------------------------
| Nov 29, 2012 | Aug 28, 2007 |
```

If you are using MySQL, then you can use the [`Date_Format()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
select 
  date_format(receivedate, '%b %e, %Y') ReceiveDate,
  date_format(sentdate, '%b %e, %Y') SentDate
from customers
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/adfbe/2)

Comment: For `TSQL` answer, It is too long for too little.

Comment: @Kaf there are multiple ways to do everything, it still answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a certain mysql function that does that.

But if you want to show the date on a site with the format (jan 24, 1998) then you can use php.

You make three queries one to take the day, one for the month and one for the year.

Then you make switch case for the month to associate it with its name (e.g. 03 -> Mar).

Answer (score 0):

On `SQL Server` you can do using `CONVERT` and `STUFF`;

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(),100),7,1,', ')
--Results: Dec 10, 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL server you want some combination of [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) and [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) like this:

```
SELECT 
   DATENAME(month, '2012-11-29 19:17:00') + ' ' + 
   CAST(DATEPART(dd, '2012-11-29 19:17:00') AS VARCHAR)+ ', ' + 
   CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, '2012-11-29 19:17:00') AS VARCHAR);
```